# Issue while comparing and updating file entries using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having entries like below in 2 files

**File_1**

```
#Windows Audio,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
Citrix Desktop Service,OS,WARNING
Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
```

**File_2**

```
#Windows Audio,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
Citrix Desktop Service,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Sync Host_5262c1bd,OS,WARNING
Sync Host_542d9c2d,OS,WARNING
Sync Host_54698e01,OS,WARNING
Sync Host_58e7b78e,OS,WARNING
Sync Host_6a739aca,OS,WARNING
```

I need to compare the two file an update **File_1** like below

```
#Windows Audio,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
Citrix Desktop Service,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
```

What it does, as the last entry in **File_2** dowsn't have **#** in front of it, so it should add that and the other **Sync Host** entries while are not available should ignore

Please let me know how can I do that

**Expected Output**

```
#Windows Audio,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
Citrix Desktop Service,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
```

Comment: Read your posting.  It is not doing what is in writing.

Comment: @jdweng: I am comparing **File_2** with **File_1** and updating the **File_1**. while ever entry present in **File_1** should be considered

Comment: The output look exactly like input.  Last row of File_2 is : Sync Host_6a739aca,OS,WARNING

Comment: @jdweng: Expected output is like **File_1** mentioned at the end

Comment: Your instructions say : "What it does, as the last entry in File_2 doesn't have # in front of it, so it should add that and the other Sync Host entries while are not available should ignore".  the last entry in file 2 is "Sync Host_6a739aca,OS,WARNING".  Why doesn't "Sync Host_6a739aca,OS,WARNING"  appear in the expected output?